# How to know the file is exist in SD Card or Internal Storage in Android

Tags: android, file, android-sdcard

How can I come to know that any file is exist or not in Android sdcard or internal storage?

Case : we don't have exact location directory. I want to check that file in any directory.

If there is any method or any example to do so please let me know.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow below samples available in stackoverflow

[Sample 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10589298/file-search-recursively)

[Sample 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12656569/recursive-method-to-search-through-folder-tree-and-find-specific-file-types)

I think above links may help

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether File exists or not by using [`File.exists()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists%28%29)

```
     File file = new File(filePathString); 
        if(file.exists()) {     
        //File is present
        }
        else{
        // File is not present,Create a new one.
       try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I don't know what is the file path. I have only name of it. Then plz tell me how to check it from whole sdcard?